# How to parse multiline response of 09 04 PID from OBD adapter in Android

Tags: android, pid, obd-ii

I am getting raw data from OBD adapter, It is getting parsed for single line but for multiline response I am not able to parse.
I used below code to parse

```
    String hexaData = getResult(); // getResult is here the raw data("4904014A4D422A490402333637364904033135303049040400000000") after parsing I am getting parsed value(JMB*36761500) which is correct and only working for single line 
        Log.i("CalID_hexa", hexaData);
        final String result = getResult();
        String workingData;
        if (result.contains(":")) {//CAN(ISO-15765) protocol.
            workingData = result.replaceAll(".:", "").substring(9);//9 is xxx49040701, xxx is bytes of information to follow.
            Matcher m = Pattern.compile("[^a-z0-9 ]", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE).matcher(convertHexToString(workingData));
            if(m.find()) workingData = result.replaceAll("0:49", "").replaceAll(".:", "");
        } else {//ISO9141-2, KWP2000 Fast and KWP2000 5Kbps (ISO15031) protocols.
            workingData = result.replaceAll("49040.", "");
        }
         calId = convertHexToString(workingData).replaceAll("[\u0000-\u001f]", "");
        L.stringStringHashMap.put("CAL_ID",calId);


public String convertHexToString(String hex) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        //49204c6f7665204a617661 split into two characters 49, 20, 4c...
        for (int i = 0; i < hex.length() - 1; i += 2) {

            //grab the hex in pairs
            String output = hex.substring(i, (i + 2));
            //convert hex to decimal
            int decimal = Integer.parseInt(output, 16);
            //convert the decimal to character
            sb.append((char) decimal);
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
```

How to parse multiline response like  below response on PID 09 04 from OBD Adapter:

```
18 DA F1 11 10 13 49 04 01 33 37 38 
18 DA F1 1D 10 13 49 04 01 33 37 38
18 DA F1 11 21 30 35 2D 52 59 45 2D
18 DA F1 11 22 41 37 34 30 00 00 55
18 DA F1 1D 21 30 36 2D 52 59 45 2D
18 DA F1 1D 22 41 37 37 30 00 00 55
```

How can I parse the above?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to parse multiple line responses as single line responses then you can first form the array from the multiple line response separating the lines by character `\n`. After forming the array of responses, you can join the strings in one single line.

Answer (score 0):

You have two issues here. The first is that you sent your request using a broadcast address, that's why two ECUs (namely, `18 DA F1 11` and `18 DA F1 1D`) answered to your request. You either have to sort these out or ask only one ECU directly.

The second is you should learn about ISO 15765-2 (also named ISO-TP), which is a transport protocol, much like TCP (or rather IP) is for Ethernet. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_15765-2 contains a rough outline.

A general notice: If you're serious about implementing OBD2 communication, write a layered architecture, in which the communication layer (BLE, TTY, TCP, etc.) sits below the vehicle protocol which ISO-TP sits on top of. On the actual application layer you can then decode the individual PIDs and their measurements.